# SAS date symput function query

Tags: sas

As part of a migration project I have come across the following function:

```
call symput('setdate',put("&sysdate"d -(0) - weekday(date()),date9.))
```

What is this function doing?

As the date today is 28/02/2023

The result is 25/02/2023

I know "weekday(Date())" is geting the day number of the week (Sunday = 0, etc.)

I know "&sysdate"d is current datetime

I know "put" comined with "symput" will asign the result to a variable called 'setdate'

I know date9. will make it ddmonyyyy format

What is the -(0) doing?

And, if the weekday (being Tuesday) = 2 then why is the result 25/02/2023? and not 26/02/2023.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more robust method of calculating dates is to use the `intnx()` function which is not only easy to use, but I think it's also easier to understand. For example, to calculate the last day of the prior week (Sat):

`intnx('week', date(), -1, 'end')`

Here's a quick example:

```
data _null_;
do dt = date() - 7 to date();
    dt2 = intnx('week', dt, -1, 'end');
    put dt= weekdate15. @23 dt2= weekdate15.;
end;
run;
```

Output:

```
dt=Tue, Feb 21, 23    dt2=Sat, Feb 18, 23
dt=Wed, Feb 22, 23    dt2=Sat, Feb 18, 23
dt=Thu, Feb 23, 23    dt2=Sat, Feb 18, 23
dt=Fri, Feb 24, 23    dt2=Sat, Feb 18, 23
dt=Sat, Feb 25, 23    dt2=Sat, Feb 18, 23
dt=Sun, Feb 26, 23    dt2=Sat, Feb 25, 23
dt=Mon, Feb 27, 23    dt2=Sat, Feb 25, 23
dt=Tue, Feb 28, 23    dt2=Sat, Feb 25, 23
```

Answer (score 0):

`-(0)` is doing nothing.  The formula `"&sysdate"d -(0) - weekday(date())` is for calculating the previous Saturday.

My guess is that the `(0)` is an adjustor for when the developer either didn't figure out the formula in their head, or it's used to tweak a run-through to the previous friday of yesterday (that would be `-(1)`) etc.